# Can someone please explain Thunderclient's git integration?

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

I am trying out Thunderclient as a lightweight alternative to Postman; for local development.

The problem I am having is integration with my project through git.

https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support#team

The documentation seems clear enough, but I'm having difficulty locating "Load From project" via vs code. Can someone provide a helpful link or video that could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open vscode settings

- Search for thunder
- Then you will find **Save To Workspace** option
- Enable the checkbox
- Then close and restart vscode.
- Now open your project it will save requests in your project folder

Hope it clear now.

Comment: Seems silly, but when no folder is open in VS Code this could be misleading since requests will continue to save be saved to default storage. Maybe making clear that you have to "Create a new folder for your project or repository", then open it, then do this procedure will be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, feel free update the documentation if needed on our GitHub page.